# mDNS in client-sided Javascript?

Tags: javascript, http, service-discovery, mdns

I have a plugin (Figma plugin) that runs in an isolated browser environment so dont have any access to Node or similar.

I need the plugin to communicate with a backend service (written in Rust) that runs on another computer. This computer can have any IP.

I understand that these technologies are typically implemented at the operating system level or within specific applications, but I was curious if it's possible to implement these in client-side JavaScript.

I've searched around but haven't found anything substantial. Has anyone in the community attempted this or could perhaps shed some light on whether it's feasible? Any insights or relevant resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

I have tried running though all available addresses on the subnet (for example everything on 192.168.1.0/24) but this will not work since the subnets could be different depending on the environment, and I haven't found a way to figure out the local address of the computer the plugin runs in.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.